# How do you access task form field data from approval workflows?

Tags: workflow, tasks, approval-process

tldr: Need to access Task Form Field data in first Approval step, but nothing shows up.

On the bigger scale, I have is a multi-step approval system. On the first approval step, the user inputs the person/group that needs to approve the second step, so I added a person/group field to that step in Task Form Fields in Sharepoint Designer. The problem is I can't access that column data for the second approval process. How do you do that?

What I've tried - Lookup window:

- Data source -> Association: Task list
- Field from source: Next approver (my Task Form Field name)
- Return field as: User Id Number (this returns -1, so I know I'm not getting it)

Find the list item (this part gets murky, nothing here I tried worked)

- Field: ID
- Value: Current Item: ID

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, it seems like you have to set a variable once the task is created, so you can store the task ID.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Collect-data-from-a-user-in-a-workflow-a1758bcc-6a93-4ca9-9b55-7821b91e80f4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ocpArticleContent

Go to Step 2: Set a workflow variable. In sharepoint 2013, I went to the approval process and clicked "Change the behavior of a single task" where I added the local variable variable value to the completion steps.