# Sharepoint 2013 - How to lookup custom string in workflow task

Tags: workflow, lookup-column, string

I'm creating a workflow that assigns a task to a person. After that person completes the task, they are required to input a string of text (a server URL) before they can press "Approve." Once this is done, I want my workflow to assign the next task to another individual, and in the email notification I want to include the server URL the previous person entered. The problem is I haven't been able to find the correct lookup procedure to reference this server URL.

How do I look-up the VM Server URL from the approval screen?

[image: Approval Page asks for Server URL]
And how do I include that string in the email that gets sent out as the next task?

[image: How do I reference Server URL in SharePoint Designer so the email will display that info?]

### Update on 1/15

Following Amal's advice, instead of referencing the Current Item ID, I tried to reference the ID matching the output task ID (picture added below). I changed the ID to reference the Task ID from the previous assigned task and now when I complete the first task it seems like the workflow is unable to progress to the next task. It seems to break the workflow. Is there something I did wrong?

I think part of the issue is that the TaskID variable is a string like this (4250c824-d81d-4d4a-b440-924901a1da95), but SharePoint only let's me retrieve it as an integer.

[image: Update 1-15]

### Solution

The problem was that I was trying to map to the ID field, and apparently that is only for integers. The TaskID is a string and needed to be mapped to the GUID field as a string. This is what worked for me:

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `CurrentItem:ID` you should need the Task Item ID.

For that you need to get the ID of the Workflow Task once its created. You can store that ID in a workflow variable and use that to get the correct Task Item.

[How do you access task form field data from approval workflows?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120193/how-do-you-access-task-form-field-data-from-approval-workflows)

Comment: I changed the ID to reference the Task ID from the previous assigned task and now when I complete the first task it seems like the workflow is unable to progress to the next task.

Comment: Ultimately your suggestion led me to the solution. The only change to your suggestion is that I needed to matchup the task ID to the GUID instead of ID. I provided an update to the original post detailing the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for sorting this out. was just about to investigate myself.
cheers!!